# MRUnit and AvroMapper

Tags: mapreduce, avro, mrunit

`AvroMapper` requires 2 parameters:

```
public static class AvroRecordMapper
        extends AvroMapper <MyRecord,Pair <CharSequence,CharSequence>>
```

and mapDriver requires 4 parameters:

```
K1 V1 K2 V2
```

Can I use `MRUnit` for unit tests with `AvroMapper`?